# Ошибка. Не делается fullscreen Activity

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь убрать статус бар и название приложения. Убирается только статус бар. В чём проблема?
Вот код класса:

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Не работает эта строка
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    }
}
```

Также когда добавляю строку в манифест, приложение вылетает.

Вот строка:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 2):

Для вашей `AppCompactActivity` надо использовать `Theme.AppCompat`

```
<style name="YourTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

и

```
android:theme="@style/YourTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй тему

```
@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen
```

В коде не рекомендую ничего скрывать, уберите этот код. Плохая практика. Дело в том, что андроид читает перед запуском тему и это лучше, чем при запуске активности

Comment: Все равно. Как только добавляю строку в манифест, так программа начинает вылетать

Comment: Важное замечание. Когда я сменил в классе активити extends AppCompactActivity на Activity. Всё заработало, но экран стал полностью черным с одним компонентом.

Comment: Ой, моя вина, не учел библиотеку `AppCompat`. Обновил ответ

Comment: Родительскую тему поменяйте во всех `styles.xml` файлах проекта