# Проблема с запуском приложения в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, исключения

В манифесте вставляю строку кода xml, которая была показана в книге:

```
<activity android:name=".SubHunter"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

В итоге когда запускаю avd, то приложение останавливается и кидает исключение. При этом если уберу 2 строчку, то все запускается. Но мне нужно, чтобы именно приложение запускалось в полный экран. Подскажите, что делать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вообще учитесь читать и понимать логи. В данном случае скорее всего `SubHunter extends AppCompatActivity` и требует саппортную тему. Попробуйте заменить на `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`, если не поможет, то добавьте к вопросу лог ошибки.

Comment: То есть саппортную тему? И правильно я понимаю, что должно быть android:theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"? Потому что у меня все это становится красным...И после AppCompat не указывает на NoTitleBar...

Comment: Имеется в виду, что при наследовании активности из библиотек поддержки нужно использовать тему из библиотек поддержки. И, да, нет там готового полноэкранного варианта, надо модифицировать по примеру: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615940/11515